# Knockoutjs css, function call

Tags: knockout.js

I am going through the tutorial from the official website:

[Knockout single page application lesson](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=webmail)

this is the view:

```
<!-- Folders -->
<ul class="folders" data-bind="foreach: folders">
    <li data-bind="text: $data, 
                   css: { selected: $data == $root.chosenFolderId() },
                   click: $root.goToFolder"></li>
</ul>
```

and the script:

```
function WebmailViewModel() {
    // Data
    var self = this;
    self.folders = ['Inbox', 'Archive', 'Sent', 'Spam'];
    self.chosenFolderId = ko.observable();

    // Behaviours    
    self.goToFolder = function(folder) { self.chosenFolderId(folder); };    
};

ko.applyBindings(new WebmailViewModel());
```

I dont' t understand 2 things:

1. the 'click:' event is calling the javascript function goToFolder, however, with no argument, how does it know which folder is clicked to set the chosenFolderId  ?
2. Correct me if I am wrong, the line css: { selected: $data == $root.chosenFolderId() } means if the current selected object $data is equal to chosenFolderId(), therefore the css with the name selected is enable ?

Cheers all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are answers:

1. By default knockout passes current context to the function that is called. In your case this is `$data` object which contains one of the following strings 'Inbox', 'Archive', 'Sent', 'Spam'.
2. Yes, you are right. This means that `selected` css class will be applied to the `<li>` element where $`data` is equal to `chosenFolderId` property of view model.

Comment: Hi Artem, thanks a lot, I understand better why the function is called with no argument, About the syntax, why the css: is called with the () of the end of chosenFolderId() ?, and click: without ?

Comment: Because you should use brackets when you have an expression in binding (i.e. "visible: Something() > 10"), if you have just function or observable you don't need to put brackets. This article help you to understand basic things: http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/06/10-things-to-know-about-knockoutjs-on.html